# Charts for black and white printing?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a couple of column charts in Google Sheets that have several columns of data. I would like to print them out in just black and white, since they are part of a larger report that doesn't need color at all. But when I choose the style for the columns, I can only specify different colors, which are tough to tell apart when printed in black and white.

Is there any way of specifying a pattern or something for the different columns, such that they will be easy to tell apart?

Comment: If a line pattern includes elements that are visible whatever the color (e.g. triangles on the line, squares, etc.), this improves the visibility no matter how it's printed.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there are 8 grayscale options for column colors, ranging from black to white. I suppose the distinguishability of those grays will depend upon print quality. I don't see any way to specify patterns that would be more clearly visible in black and white.